# Knowing that, in $\mathbb{N}$, $m+n \neq n$, show that if $n\leq m$ and $m\leq n$, then $m=n$.

Tags: real-analysis, axioms, natural-numbers

> Given the theorem that, if $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ (the "counting numbers" without zero), then $m+n \neq n$.
>
> Prove the reflexive property in $\mathbb{N}$; that is, if $n \leq m$ and $m \leq n$, then $m = n$.

My go was to try to derive a contradiction from the first theorem, but I was not able to relate them. It is as follows:

$n \leq m$ by definition means ($n < m$) or ($n = m$),

this means $ \exists \ k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ m = n + k$ or n = m

Then the same definition is for $\ n \leq m $.

So I want to show that the first case ($ m = n + k$) cannot be true, and then we will be left with $n = m$ as desired.

Any suggestion on how to show that (or possibly another way of deriving the contradiction)?

Thanks,

Comment: That's not the reflexive property, it is (lax) antisymmetry.

Comment: It is worth mentioning I suppose that $\Bbb N$ for you must be referring to $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ rather than $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ since $0+n=n$ happens to be true.

Comment: So, suppose all three that $n\leq m$, $m\leq n$ and $n\neq m$.  Then we have $n<m$ meaning there is some positive number $k$ such that $m=n+k$.  We also have because of $m<n$ that there is some positive integer $\ell$ such that $n=m+\ell$.  We get putting these together then that $n = n + k + \ell$,. which based on the alluded to theorem in the first line is impossible.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the reasoning, but could not see how n = n + k + ℓ contradicts $ m+n \neq n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions: $(1).\forall x,y\in \Bbb N\,(x+y\in \Bbb N)$.... $(2).$ $+$ is associative and commutative on $\Bbb N$.... $(3).  \forall x,y \in \Bbb N\,(x+y\ne x).$

Let $\Bbb N_0=\Bbb N\cup \{0\}$ where $\forall x \in \Bbb N_0\,(x+0=0+x=x).$ We easily verify that $+$ is associative and commutative on $\Bbb N_0.$

$(\bullet).\; 0\not \in \Bbb N.\;$ Proof: If $0\in \Bbb N,$ let $0=y\in \Bbb N.$ Then there exists some (any) $x\in \Bbb N$ such that $x=x+0=x+y,$ contrary to $(3).$

For $m,n\in \Bbb N$ we have $m\le n\iff \exists k\in \Bbb N_0\,(m+k=n).$

Let $m,n\in \Bbb N$ with $m\le n \le m.$ Let $k,k'\in \Bbb N_0$ such that $m+k=n$ and $n+k'=m.$ Then $$m+n=(n+k')+(m+k)=(m+n)+(k'+k).$$ Now with $m'=m+n$ and $n'=k'+k\in \Bbb N_0$ we have $m'\in \Bbb N$ and $m'+n'=m',$  which by $(3)$ implies that $k'+k=n'\not \in \Bbb N.$ So $k'+k=0.$

Now $(k'=0\implies n=n+0=n+k'=m),$ while $(k=0\implies m=m+0=m+k=n).$

But $k'\ne 0 \ne k \implies k',k\in \Bbb N\implies k'+k\in \Bbb N\implies k'+k\ne 0$ by $(\bullet),$  contrary to $k'+k=0.$ So this case does not occur.

Comment: Thank you! I admit that I am at the beginning of a real analysis course and your proof took me a while to barely understand. I might need ages to reach such mathematical maturity!

Comment: I have some experience with axiomatic foundations, in which it is easy to slip in an assumption, so I spelled them out at the start.... This  could be re-written to "internalize" it to $\Bbb N$ without $0$ but it would be the same proof with a lot more writing.

Comment: Sorry. Could you please clarify how did you deduce " ′+′=′ " from " ′=+ and ′=′+∈ℕ0 " ?

Comment: We have (by definition of $m'$ and $n'$) that  $m'=m+n$ and $n'=k'+k.$ And we have (by def'n of $k$ and $k'$) that $m=n+k$ and $n=m+k'.$ Now from the displayed line we have $m'=m+n=(m+n)+(k'+k)=(m')+(n')$.... The point of defining $m'$ and $n$' was to apply the theorem you quote: If $m',n'\in \Bbb N$ then $m'\ne m'+n'$, but we DO have $m'=m+n\in \Bbb N$ and we DO have $m'=m'+n'$ so it is not possible that $n'\in \Bbb N$ as that would violate the theorem. So $0=n'=k'+k.$

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There seems to be an inverse relation between the complexity of a structure and the degree of difficulty of studying its axiomatic roots. I would rather study ZFC (the Theory Of Everything) than Peano Arithmetic :)